# Temperature changes in a planet with much larger ice caps

Tags: climate, earth-like, seasons

I'm building an RPG world and the ice caps are rather large.
[image: World that I'm constructing, about the size of earth]

How big of an effect would it have on the climate and seasons of said world? Would it be slightly colder or would it be similar to an ice age?

Comment: Welcome to the site Tobias.  Nice map, what'd you use to create it?

Comment: @TobiasFizzlewig Will you tell me how you made that map? I know you used donjon

Comment: @XandarTheZenon I honestly clicked random 4-dozen times until something similar to what I was thinking of came up. Also, if you know where I made it, how do you not know how it was made?

Comment: I meant the seed, and ocean specifics, like what percent ocean.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon Oh, well my answer above explains that as well.

Comment: Yeah, just thought I'd explain myself

Answer (score 2):

It would have to be colder, or the ice caps would melt. Other than that, I can't think of any adverse differences it would make. I don't think that this map would qualify as ice age, but maybe somewhere between ice-age and modern Earth.